# What does '--' dash dash mean in CSS property value

Tags: css

I bought a website template which used -- in their CSS property value. This gives the errors property value expected and at-rule or selector expected. I know of -- being used in for CSS property but never for property value. What does the -- used here mean?

```
.my-sm-nn1 {
    margin-top: --0.25rem !important;
  }
```

Comment: `-` is negative that is before `0.25rem`

Comment: `--` is used before property take a look at it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40055654/what-do-these-double-dash-prefixed-css-properties-do

Comment: I guess its a variable. But Im not sure variables can starts with numeric values in css.

Comment: yeah I'm pretty sure this is either a double negative or just wrong

Comment: variable name can't start with numeric value

Comment: @FredStark what do you mean by _double negative_?

Comment: @Ibnelaiq I know that is this how it is normally used, but the code I got from my the template used it in the property value instead, so I am trying to figure out why they did it is this manner.

Comment: Check it's occurrence in css file, maybe it is typo mistake?

Comment: testing out some stuff, looks like `--something` isn't a valid property anywhere, so not a double negative, just a stuff up

Comment: yeah, I also tried to manipulate it here. It is not a valid property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use is absolutely useless. If you try run your code you will see the browser ignores it, it looks like:

[image]

Sorry to say, but unfortunately you bought a template which is not perfectly clean. This can happen. Maybe it was just a typo by the developer, maybe he didn't care. Hopefully the rest of your template works as expected.

You can run the code and try yourself. The line `margin-top: --0.25rem !important;` will just be ignored by any browser.

```css
.outer {
  background-color: orange;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
.inner {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: solid 1px fuchsia;
  margin-top: --0.25rem !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
   <div class="inner">
   </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** if you wonder why is there now more CSS then in your question: I like to add `background-colors` and `borders` to elements to be 100% sure that some rules do or do not effect any styling of the elements.

Comment: One mistake in the code doesn't really mean that the template is "not super clean" We haven't seen the rest of it...

Comment: @OOPSStudio if "super clean" means there is 0 lines of rubbish in there. We then find 1 line of rubbish, then it looses the "super clean" flag.

Comment: One could argue that "super clean" is not the same as "perfectly clean" But still, I can see your point.

Comment: @OOPSStudio agree! updated the answer with "perfectly clean"